# How do the existing ways to do formal CT relate to each other?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I can see three ways to "do formal category theory":

1. Yoneda structures à la Street-Walters.
2. cosmoi à la Street.
3. proarrow equipments.

It seems to me that 2. is older than 1., and a particular case thereof (you impose more requests on $y_A : A \to PA$ asking that there is an adjoint to the pseudofunctor $P : {\cal K}^\text{coop} \to {\cal K}$).

Is there, instead, a relation between Yoneda structures, cosmoi, and proarrow equipments?

Comment: Street used the word "cosmos" in more than one way (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cosmos); which are you thinking of?

Comment: I use the definition of *fibrational cosmos* given in Street's "Cosmoi of internal categories" at 2.11 and reprised from *Elementary cosmoi* (I should add a few lines to the nLab page, shouldn't I?). See below for an additional question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Street's "fibrational cosmoi" are indeed a special case of, or rather a particular way to construct, a Yoneda structure.  They are substantially less general, since Yoneda structures and equipments include the case of enriched categories, but fibrational cosmoi do not.  (Street also used the word "cosmos" later for a bicategory of the form $W \mathrm{Prof}$, which is more like the horizontal part of an equipment, but doesn't contain information about the functors as distinct from the representable profunctors.)

Yoneda structures and equipments are similar in that they both enhance a 2-category with information about "profunctors", but they do it in slightly different ways, so that in constructing examples one has to make different choices about how to deal with size.  Namely, in an equipment (as originally defined), all proarrows are composable; thus if we include large categories as objects, we also need to include large-set-valued profunctors as proarrows; or we can consider only small categories and small-set-valued profunctors.  On the other hand, in a Yoneda structure all profunctors are small-"set"-valued, but we are required to include large categories and even "locally large" categories, since the presheaf category of a non-small category is not generally locally small; thus not every category has an identity proarrow and not all proarrows can be composed.

Thus, although morally they contain about the same information, it's hard to prove a precise comparison abstractly.  The best I'm aware of is [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04070) of Koudenburg, which uses a generalization of equipments to "hypervirtual double categories" and shows that under reasonable assumptions, presheaf categories can be given a universal property therein that corresponds exactly to the axioms of a Yoneda structure on a certain subcategory.

Comment: Thanks. I have in fact another question; in his "Fibrations in bicategories" published on Cahiers, Street defines the notion of a fibrational bicategory: it is a bicategory that admits finite bilimits and bicoequinverters, preserved by bipulling back (..."pulling biback"?) along the leg of a fibration -which is a special kind of span-. How does this definition relates to a fibrational cosmos? Is in only an accidental clash of nomenclature or...?

Comment: (I see Koudenburg's paper is quite long; can you point me to the place where this property is described?)

Comment: Terminology-wise, nowadays people often leave off the "bi-" in front of bicategorical notions; as long as you know you're working in a bicategory with everything bicategorical you can just say "pullback" and hence "pulling back".  Both a fibrational bicategory and a fibrational cosmos use the notion of two-sided internal fibration, but are not otherwise the same; for more than that you can read the definitions yourself.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian Koudenburg's comparison is Proposition 5.6 in his paper.

Comment: " Both a fibrational bicategory and a fibrational cosmos use the notion of two-sided internal fibration, but are not otherwise the same; for more than that you can read the definitions yourself." The point of representation/comparison theorems is precisely to disprove this statement: many objects (especially in CT) arise with utterly different definitions and then they are proved equal :-) thanks, though.